# Java 11 not accepting self signed certificate

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

I'm running into a weird problem with Tomcat 9 and OpenJDK 11.0.2 on a Linux server. Tomcat is configured as HTTPS only, no HTTP port (there is HTTP port but it redirects to HTTPS). Tomcat hosts a bunch of webapps, and being HTTPS only was one of the security requirements.

One of these webapps actually have to connect to the same Tomcat (to the manager app) over HTTPS to deploy other webapps automatically (simple copy into webapps folder is not an option because autodeploy of WARs is disabled). The app was throwing SSL errors because the HTTPS cert for the Tomcat is self signed. No actual users are using these apps, other servers are connecting to it, so self-signed is "fine" here, and we could get the other servers to accept self-signed certs.

However for the life of me, I can't setup the JVM to accept the self signed cert the Tomcat is configured to use. I tried two different approaches.

Approach 1:

1. Created a self signed certificate with OpenSSL (so that it has SAN fields)
2. Converted to PKCS12 and created a JKS keystore for the Tomcat
3. Imported the self-signed certificate to the Java cacerts file as a trustedCertEntry

Approach 2:

1. Created a CA key and certificate with OpenSSL
2. Imported the CA certificate to the Java cacerts file as a trustedCertEntry
3. Created a new key
4. Created a CSR with the key
5. Signed the CSR with the CA key and certificate, and created a new certificate
6. Converted to PKCS12 and created a JKS keystore for the Tomcat

In both cases, remote server is accepting the certificate, but webapp on local Tomcat keeps throwing the same exception:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I've done similar configurations before, and it always worked. Maybe I am missing something small here, I'm not sure now.

Technical details for approach 1:

Here is the self-signed cert in the cacerts file:

```
keytool -list -v -cacerts -alias tomcat
Enter keystore password:
Alias name: tomcat
Creation date: Feb 18, 2021
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=xxx, OU=xxx, O=xxx, L=xxx, ST=xxx, C=xxx
Issuer: CN=xxx, OU=xxx, O=xxx, L=xxx, ST=xxx, C=xxx
Serial number: e582a6448ae33c84
Valid from: Tue Feb 16 17:23:34 CET 2021 until: Fri Feb 14 17:23:34 CET 2031
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: 2B:B2:3D:4C:42:12:49:EF:66:C1:15:66:A1:58:39:12:2D:A0:A6:0D
         SHA256: B6:BA:23:93:C8:AA:C0:F6:3F:3F:FB:B6:8E:0F:CE:A9:0D:55:F9:BB:8D:14:82:C4:39:12:D8:67:99:B9:FB:63
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: xxx
  DNSName: xxx
  IPAddress: x.x.x.x
]
```

Same in the JKS keystore for Tomcat:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore tomcat-keystore.jks
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: tomcat
Creation date: Feb 16, 2021
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=xxx, OU=xxx, O=xxx, L=xxx, ST=xxx, C=xxx
Issuer: CN=xxx, OU=xxx, O=xxx, L=xxx, ST=xxx, C=xxx
Serial number: e582a6448ae33c84
Valid from: Tue Feb 16 17:23:34 CET 2021 until: Fri Feb 14 17:23:34 CET 2031
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: 2B:B2:3D:4C:42:12:49:EF:66:C1:15:66:A1:58:39:12:2D:A0:A6:0D
         SHA256: B6:BA:23:93:C8:AA:C0:F6:3F:3F:FB:B6:8E:0F:CE:A9:0D:55:F9:BB:8D:14:82:C4:39:12:D8:67:99:B9:FB:63
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: xxx
  DNSName: xxx
  IPAddress: x.x.x.x
]
```

Technical details for approach 2:

Here is my CA in cacerts:

```
keytool -list -v -cacerts -alias MY_CA
Enter keystore password:
Alias name: MY_CA
Creation date: Feb 18, 2021
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: EMAILADDRESS=yyy, CN=yyy, OU=yyy, O=yyy, L=yyy, ST=yyy, C=yyy
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=yyy, CN=yyy, OU=yyy, O=yyy, L=yyy, ST=yyy, C=yyy
Serial number: a9dc4764a1b6c856
Valid from: Thu Feb 18 21:19:59 CET 2021 until: Wed Feb 13 21:19:59 CET 2041
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: 16:FE:9A:BC:9F:05:9F:03:31:61:B2:29:CF:AD:E4:C4:44:6A:6A:92
         SHA256: 5B:BB:CA:A2:96:D5:C5:21:48:03:E9:73:20:13:92:91:E6:3D:32:2F:E4:19:83:1D:49:BF:03:23:48:D7:61:B5
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 25 08 24 A4 78 B1 C7 3B   BD D1 BA E2 96 D1 94 4C  %.$.x..;.......L
0010: 6A A3 7A 64                                        j.zd
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 25 08 24 A4 78 B1 C7 3B   BD D1 BA E2 96 D1 94 4C  %.$.x..;.......L
0010: 6A A3 7A 64                                        j.zd
]
]
```

Here is the Tomcat JKS:

```
[tsmadmin@cs13bapp02 security]$ /opt/Avaya/javas/jdk-11.0.2/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore tomcat2.jks
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: tomcat
Creation date: Feb 18, 2021
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=xxx, OU=xxx, O=xxx, L=xxx, ST=xxx, C=xxx
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=yyy, CN=yyy, OU=yyy, O=yyy, L=yyy, ST=yyy, C=yyy
Serial number: badb5c4856595561
Valid from: Thu Feb 18 21:38:30 CET 2021 until: Sun Feb 16 21:38:30 CET 2031
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: 8F:CD:8B:6F:4D:00:D8:8D:2F:E6:25:4A:97:69:28:A0:CF:2D:5C:EA
         SHA256: A7:9D:36:6C:E2:4C:2C:3D:C0:E9:FB:4B:19:9F:15:B5:59:CA:23:27:64:1A:78:51:02:4C:DF:3E:A1:08:43:7C
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 25 08 24 A4 78 B1 C7 3B   BD D1 BA E2 96 D1 94 4C  %.$.x..;.......L
0010: 6A A3 7A 64                                        j.zd
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: xxx
  IPAddress: x.x.x.x
]
```

In both cases, I enabled debug SSL log in Java (-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake), but I can't really make head nor tail of it. I can only make out this error:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|30|https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-9|2021-02-18 17:54:25.184 CET|Alert.java:232|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "certificate_unknown"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|30|https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-9|2021-02-18 17:54:25.184 CET|TransportContext.java:313|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:672)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:627)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:443)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:422)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:634)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:499)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:238)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1567)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)}

)
```

The same Tomcat being both the client and the server, everything is logged twice for the TLS, which makes reading it more difficult.

Any advice? Even something as what to look into. I can attach more logs, I just don't know what I'm looking for in SSL debug log.

Answer (score 1):

Friendly, quick review...

SSL is about trust.

A truststore is who you trust.

A keystore/certificate is who you identify yourself as.

So, your tomcat instance will need to trust itself.  Meaning that it will need to have its self signed certificate in its truststore file.

### Steps

Note:  These steps assume that you are not doing [Mutual Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication).

There are a couple ways of doing this, but the way that I do it, is to use a Java application called [InstallCert](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert).

With your self signed certificate running on your tomcat instance, run InstallCert and a new jssecacerts1 file will be created in the directory you ran the InstallCert program.

You will then need to start your tomcat instance using this new jssecacerts1 file by adding the following parameters to your tomcat startup script:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="<directories>/jssecacerts1" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="changeit"
```

If everything goes correctly, when your application makes requests to itself over https://localhost everything should work correctly.

Comment: Well, I tried. When running InstallCert, it says "Loading KeyStore cacerts... No errors, certificate is already trusted". Nevertheless I created the jssecacerts file, and used it as truststore as you mentioned. I also tried using the original cacerts file as truststore. Still, I keep getting the same error. It's almost like Tomcat is not running with the JVM I believe it to be running with, but linux process output says it does.

Comment: Can you verify that you requested the localhost certificate by entering https://localhost<:port>?

Comment: Yes, I tried with localhost, IP, and FQDN also, connection worked for all. Certificate itself contained FQDN and IP address in the SAN fields.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up ignoring all certificate errors in Java code. It is internal application only, will never see a request from public internet, so it is okay.

Comment: That's not a valid answer to the question... Yeah, you could also disable SSL and would be much cleaner solution.